# Why is .Net MVC architecture so overcomplicated vs Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, architecture

*Note: This is far from a post on x is better than x. Pleased dont go there.*

I'm a .Net guy and always have been, I've used the MVC framework since early version 2 Betas and every version since. Over the past few months I've been messing around with Rails and I have a question about architecture that seems to differ hugely between the 2 platforms. (Based on the community and questions on sites such as SO)

In .Net MVC we are encouraged to separate concerns, create separate projects to handle Data Access, Business Logic and the View, we are also told that we should convert our Data objects to ViewModels before they hit the view etc

In Rails, things seem allot simpler, we have an object that contains Validation, DataAccess (Via active record) and other logical properties and we simply ship that to the View and display it.

So why in one framework is this methodology acceptable and in the other it's deemed wrong and we all end up writing more code and creating more files.

Note : I'm no Rails expert and I really am not trying to compare which is better than x, I am looking at the high level architecture of the 2 frameworks and working out what it's acceptable in one but not the other.

Comment: Gorilla vs Shark? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: No, I've clearly stated I'm not asking which is better. My question is why is complicated architecture the norm for .Net MVC yet rails supports the complete opposite.

Comment: The fact this question has been stared 4 times in 10 minutes should show that this has value to the community.

Comment: I was one who starred it :). I wasn't having a go at the question, it was merely in jest. I am an ASP.NET MVC Developer full time, so I starred it because I'd be interested to see what the answer is.

Comment: Oh, fair play - I though you were one of the 2 who voted to close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what type of application you are developing and how much you expect it to grow.

For trivial applications there is no need to complicate things with different view and domain models (but you might want to use seperate view models and entities: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/).

For CRUD applications you don't have to wrap your data access in an abstraction such as repository pattern.

But if you expect to code anything other than trivial or CRUD applications I encourage you to do so. Patterns and principles aid you the day you want to start to maintain your application. You get smaller more well defined classes and the business logic is made in one place instead of all over your application.

I've written a small blog entry about why I use abstractions: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/data-layer-the-right-way/

And why encapsulation is important: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/06/protect-your-data/

Comment: This is whats influenced me over and over while using .Net MVC - But more complicated web apps are written in Rails they dont employ the pattern.

Comment: Which pattern? And CRUD applications can fairly large too, but they still don't have to have that much business logic.

Comment: Sorry Pattern is the wrong word, but the ViewModels, the abstraction the rails apps I look at 'dont seem to care'.

Comment: Well. You don't need view models in ASP.NET MVC either. I use them to adapt the MODEL to the view (as transforming a user list to a SelectList) and to reduce security risks (as in removing fields that may not be edited).